# multi language indexing and SEO juice

Tags: seo, subdomain, hreflang

Can someone explain how multi-language indexing works so that automatic redirects preserve the SEO juice of the source page but recognize geo tagging when searching?

For example, 
https://www.fitbit.com/aria

redirects to 
https://www.fitbit.com/uk/aria

when searching the UK. When inspecting element, there's no rel canonical or hreflang, only a script. What is this script doing?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time they redirect to the specific folder. In that folder at the webspace you will find the translated files. Big communities use a translation file, were they just translate line per line.